# Vi how to yank an aren without specifying a buffer and paste

Tags: vi, paste, yank

I may want to yank (copy?) by marking from certain point to certain point and paste, but I want to do it without specifying any buffer. As we do in gedit by selecting text and copy-paste.

Comment: Have you tried the visual mode?

Comment: @tstenner Now I googled and found what is visual mode :) It is working as I supposed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use visual mode: type `v`, then use the arrows to mark the area you wish to copy, and then type `y` to yank